# unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012, warnings

this is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
int a, b, somma, massimo;
printf("Inserire il primo valore: A =");
scanf_s("%d", a);
printf("Inserire il secondo valore: B =");
scanf_s("%d", b);
if (b > 0) {    //1
    printf("B = %d e positivo", b);
} else {
    printf("B = %d e negativo", b);
}
if (a % 2 == 0){    //2
    printf("A = %d e pari", a);
} else {
    printf("A = %d e dispari", a);
}
somma = a + b;  //3
printf("A + B = %d", somma);
if (a < 0) {    //4
    a = -a;
}
if (b < 0) {
    b = -b;
}
massimo = a + b;
printf("Il numero più grande ottenibile con questi due numeri A, B e %d", massimo);
}
```

when i try to compile it gives me this warning:

1>c:\users\mario\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\controlla a e b\main.c : error C4335: Mac file format detected: please convert the source file to either DOS or UNIX format

1>c:\users\mario\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\controlla a e b\main.c(1): warning C4067: unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline

Comment: Make sure the text compiler's input character set encoding is the same used to store the text file. gcc. for example uses UTF-8 by default, so you should store the text in the same format. For VS you have to check yourself. And for the string literals, you have to make sure the target encoding is configured properly (on gcc also UTF-8 by default).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove all non-[ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) characters from your files or set your editor and compiler to accept UTF-8.

Comment: Bad advice, as OP wants ot include native language.

Comment: sorry but I'm not understanding what is wrong. even deleting comments error remains.

Comment: Try with a simple hello world program to check your toolchain. But I'm 99% sure you still got a non-ASCII character somewhere.

Comment: most likely a ;

Comment: In case anyone else runs into this, for me it was an extra quote at the end of an include. `#include "SomeFile.h""` <<< extra quote

Comment: Ran into this issue as well and it was a semi-colon ";"

Comment: In my case it was a semicolon after an include statement

Comment: Good call, @Levitikon - For me, it was a semicolon on the end, dreaming in C#.

Answer (score 1):

I found that this error can appear due to a poorly constructed #define, such as:

```
#define USE_THIS  true;

...

#if USE_THIS
<some code>
#endif
```

Obviously you don't use the semicolon.

This is not exactly relevant to the above example, but I included it here just in case someone searches for this error message.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the wrong encoding type, this warning can also generate with incorrect end of line sequence. So try changing the same.

In VSCode, on the bottom-right click on CRLF (or LF depending on the default setting). A popup will appear; choose the required sequence.